# Building Bootstrap with Less to change the @icon-font-path

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, bower

I use boostrap with `bower` and `gulp`.

First time I copied the `bootstrap.css` from the `bower_components` to my site's `dist` folder and everything seemd to work.

Hovever I observed that I have no `glyphicons`. This because of the fonts, that I keep in a relative folder other that defined in `bootstrap.css`

I observed that there is `less` folder in bootstrap directory having the `variables.less` file:

```
//** Load fonts from this directory.
@icon-font-path:          "../fonts/";
```

OK, perhaps if I change that relative path in the `variables.less`, take with gulp the `bootstrap.less` and output as css in my `dist` folder, it may work, but what if I update bootstrap then I will loose all my modifications...

```
bower_components
-- bootstrap   
---- less 
------ bootstrap.less
------ variables.less // @icon-font-path = "../fonts/"
------ ... 
---- fonts
------ glyphicons.ttf // etc 

dist
-- css
---- bootstrap
------ bootstrap.css // here I need @icon-font-path = "../../fonts/bootstrap/"
-- fonts
---- bootstrap
------ glyphicons.ttf // etc
```

Is there a way to override that value with a custom file with gulp?

**Restrictions**

- I don't want to change any file in the `bower_components` folder because they will be replaced on the next bower restore operation. So I can't modify directly the `bootstrap.less` nor `variables.less` files from the bower folder...
- As that folder structure is used by multiple modules, I can't change the font location to adapt it to the existing CSS bootstrap file, so my problem is to adapt *the CSS* via the less and gulp, not to move fonts to correspond to the existing CSS...

Comment: You can create your own variables file to override the default ones. My structure is a little different than yours so I'm not sure how to advise on that. It would go something like this, create a  `mysite.variables.less` file with your custom variables. Then add `@import "path/to/mysite.variables.less"` to `bootstrap.less` _or_ create a `/css/styles.less` file that has `@import "path/to/vendor/bootstrap.less"` and `@import "path/to/mysite.variables.less` which you'd have to point gulp to.

Comment: @hungerstar, thanks for the suggestion. I gave more details in a answer bellow!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I was be able to override that variable by doing the follwing:

```
/bower_components
--/bootstrap
----/less
------/boostrap.less
------/variables.less
----/fonts
------/glyp..etc..ttf

/dev
--/bootstrap
----/main.less
----/myVariables.less

/dist
--/bootstrap
----/bootstrap[.min].css
--/fonts
----/bootstrap
------/glyp..etc...ttf
```

The content of `myVariables.less`:

```
//** Load Bootsrap fonts from this directory.
@icon-font-path:          "../../fonts/bootstrap/";
```

The content of `main.less` is the folowing:

```
@import '../../../bower_components/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less';
// override boostrap variables
@import 'variables.less';
```

The *override* magic lasts in the fact that [`less variables are lazy loaded`](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading) and the *latest* declaration/attribution wins the others when the file is compiled.

So the bootstrap sources for the `gulp` processing are the following:

```
  css:   devFolder + '/bootstrap/main.less'            // compile/minimize to css
fonts: bowerFolder + '/bootstrap/dist/fonts/*.*'       // copy to dist
   js: bowerFolder + '/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js' // minimize to dist
```

Articles to read :

- [Adding Less to our build](http://www.bengladwell.com/assembling-a-frontend-stack-part-4-bootstrap-less-and-livereload/#addinglesstoourbuild)
- [LESS lazy loading](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to override bootstrap `icon-font-path` variable here. Referencing the glyphicons, that are in `bower_components`, from the stylesheet in `dist` is not how this problem should be handled.

In fact, the local resources on which your application depends should be deployed to `dist`, and that includes `glyphicons`.

You could make a gulp task so as to copy resources to `dist`. Here is an example:

```
gulp.task('copy:resources', function () {
    var glyphiconsGlob = 'bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/*.*';

    return gulp.src(glyphiconsGlob).pipe(gulp.dest(conf.paths.dist + 'css/fonts/'));
});
```

You might have to adapt the path in `gulp.dest` according to where the file `bootstrap.css` is in `dist` folder.

Comment: I don't see the structure of the `dist` folder in the description of the question. Is the `site` folder your *dist* folder?

Comment: yes, the site is the dist folder... i will fix the OP

Comment: for me the problem is to say to CSS where should it search the font, not move the font where is expected in CSS...

Comment: My point is that you see the problem the wrong way, and that the `dist` folder should be autonomous: if I package it and deliver to someone, that one should be able to play with my application. But anyway, you have the right to think otherwise and not accept the answer, I'm ok with that:)

Comment: Oh, Michael, thanks for trying to help, your help is appreciated... But I know how to move files with gulp from a dir to another... Is more complicated for me to adapt the `@icon-font-path` variable to my needs, this is why I asked the experts from SO...

Comment: by the way, if I will pack the application, the `dist` folder contains all files I need, so is autonomous for packaging

Comment: Well, if you want to go with the variable overriding it shouldn't be much of a problem. Basically you *import* `bootstrap.less` index file and then override the variable.

Comment: How exactly should I *import* and *override* with gulp?

Comment: gulp is not involved in this import/override process. In a stylesheet, say *styles.less* you import *bootstrap.less* and after that you customize `icon-font-path`. Gulp less task will compile *styles.less* to css.

Comment: *variables.less* with the wrong path is already included in *bootstrap.less*, so I am not sure how can I *customize* it in *styles.less*